# Where is iOS downloaded files in Catalina Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, finder, catalina

My brother-in-law asks me to update his iPhone 6s by using my MacBook Pro. And my MacBook Pro has Catalina OS. So there is no iTunes, I use **Finder** to connect iPhone to my laptop and then I saw below picture:

[image]

So I press `update` and after some `next`, `yes`, `continue`, I saw below picture:

[image]

This is so weird because we don't see any progress bar, and we don't know when this update will end! - *BIG ISSUE* - so after one hour we decide to stop this damn update way and my MacBook Pro has 250GB hard disk. before download, I had 200 GB free and now I have 198.5GB free capacity.

#### Question: where is the iOS download directory? I wanna delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I find the right answer, all updates are at:

```
~/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
```

For seeing on Finder enter below command on Terminal:

```
open ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
```